# Diferença entre Handler e Thread

Tags: android

Fiz um app de teste em que gostaria de ver um `ProgressBar` sendo atualizando simulando uma tarefa de longa duração. Inicialmente tentei utilizar `Handler` pois depois de algumas pesquisas vi que seu uso era recomendado:

```
        final int tempoDeEspera = 500;
        new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                SystemClock.sleep(tempoDeEspera);
                progressBar.setProgress(1);
                SystemClock.sleep(tempoDeEspera);
                progressBar.setProgress(2);
                SystemClock.sleep(tempoDeEspera);
                progressBar.setProgress(3);
                SystemClock.sleep(tempoDeEspera);
                progressBar.setProgress(4);
                SystemClock.sleep(tempoDeEspera);
                progressBar.setProgress(5);
            }
        });
```

Mas só consegui o resultado esperado usando `Thread`.

```
        final int tempoDeEspera = 500;
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                SystemClock.sleep(tempoDeEspera);
                progressBar.setProgress(1);
                SystemClock.sleep(tempoDeEspera);
                progressBar.setProgress(2);
                SystemClock.sleep(tempoDeEspera);
                progressBar.setProgress(3);
                SystemClock.sleep(tempoDeEspera);
                progressBar.setProgress(4);
                SystemClock.sleep(tempoDeEspera);
                progressBar.setProgress(5);
            }
        }).start();
```

Gostaria de saber os detalhes das duas implementações e quais as situações em que cada um deve ser utilizado.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Primeiro, um conceito básico (se você já sabe essa parte, pode pular para o último parágrafo):

Existe o *thread* principal, também chamado de *UI thread*, cuja função central é executar operações de *UI* (interface de usuário), isto é, que atualizam a tela do aplicativo, como exibir textos, imagens, etc. Este *thread* não deve ser sobrecarregado com operações não relacionadas a UI que sejam muito pesadas, sob pena de causar os famosos `ANR`s, isto é, avisos de atraso na atualização de tela que causam travamentos na responsividade do aplicativo.

E há os *threads* secundários (qualquer *thread* que não seja o principal), estes sim adequados para operações mais pesadas que não sejam de UI, mas que não têm acesso direto à fila de execução do *thread* principal e portanto não é possível chamar operações de atualização da tela diretamente por eles; são necessários `Handlers` para isso, que são objetos que "postam" uma operação de UI na fila de operações a serem executadas pelo *thread* principal (a isso se chama postar uma "mensagem" ou `Runnable` no thread principal). A diferença entre uma mensagem (classe `Message`) e um Runnable é mínima; ambos são trechos de código executável, sendo que `Message` armazena uma referência para um objeto que pode ser importante para o código sendo executado (muitas vezes isso não é necessário, bastando passar apenas um `Runnable` para o *thread* através do método `Handler.post(Runnable)`).

No seu caso, você tem um *thread* secundário executando operações não-UI (as chamadas a `sleep()`) e que de tempos em tempos precisa comunicar ao thread principal que o componente de UI `ProgressBar` precisa ser atualizado (essa operação de UI seria a chamada a `ProgressBar.setProgress()`). Como já dito o seu *thread* secundário não tem acesso direto à fila de execução do *thread* principal e para postar uma "mensagem" para o thread principal executar ele deveria usar um `Handler`. O código ficaria por exemplo assim:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
final int tempoDeEspera = 500;
int i;

new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            SystemClock.sleep(tempoDeEspera);
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    progressBar.setProgress(i);
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();
```

**Obs.:** Não testei para ver se esse código compila, mas ele serve para ilustrar o conceito de `Handler` e a diferença entre operações de `UI` e não-`UI` e os respectivos *threads* que as executam.

Exemplos de operações pesadas que exigem processamento e portanto devem ser executadas em um *thread* separado: operações de I/O, como acesso à rede (requisições HTTP em geral, como acesso a URLs), escrita de arquivos e no banco de dados SQLite, processamentos matemáticos pesados, etc.

Uma complementação: no seu caso funcionou sem o `Handler` porque a operação `ProgressBar.setProgress()` [executa um post() internamente](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.2_r1/android/widget/ProgressBar.java#ProgressBar.setProgress%28int%29) (a `ProgressBar` herda esse método de `View`), que põe a atualização da `ProgressBar` na fila de execução do *thread* principal. Mas nem todos os componentes de UI fazem isso, de forma que o `Handler` continua sendo útil em muitos casos.

Comment: Bela resposta! Mas minha dúvida não é sobre o conceito de `MainThread`, isto é bem básico. O que eu gostaria de saber é por que a versão com `Handler` não funcionou. Mas acho que já sei a resposta: provavelmente tenho que usar um `post` diferente para cada `setProgress` certo?

Comment: Sim, isso mesmo! Porque enquanto o seu `post` ocupou o thread de UI, não deixou o `post` feito internamente pelo `setProgress` e acrescentado à fila de execução do thread principal executar. Os cinco `setProgress` em seguida foram executados rapidamente e na sequência sem dar tempo de perceber isso visualmente.