# Quais são as principais diferenças entre Handler, Thread e AsyncTask?

Tags: android, multithreading, asynctask

A documentação do Android pode acabar sendo um pouco confusa para quem está começando entender melhor quais são as diferenças entre um `Handler`, um `Thread` e um `AsyncTask`.

`Handlers` são *background `Threads`* que possibilitam a comunicação com a interface de usuário. Atualizar uma barra de progresso, por exemplo, pode ser feito com um `Handler`, mas também pode ser criado com um `AsyncTask`, o que confunde um pouco o entendimento sobre este tópico.

Quais são as principais **diferenças** entre `Handler`, `Thread` e `AsyncTask`?

Comment: Não. Quero algo que exemplifique a **diferença** entre os *três*.

Comment: Handler e thread são coisas diferentes, não se podem comparar. AsyncTask usa internamente um handler e um thread.

Comment: são coisas diferentes mas que tem uma ligação e podem interagir. Acho que ele quer é a explicação de como e quando isso acontece. Não necessariamente compará-los.

Comment: Exatamente, estou procurando diferenciar os três dado que eles funcionam sobre um mesmo contexto.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Thread

Um *thread* é uma linha de execução de código dentro de um aplicativo. Um aplicativo pode ter vários *threads* em execução num mesmo momento. Em outras palavras, *threads* permitem a um aplicativo ter comportamento multitarefa. No Java, a classe `Thread` é uma representação de um *thread* da Máquina Virtual Java ou JVM (que não necessariamente corresponde a um *thread* do sistema operacional hospedeiro, mas isso não vem ao caso).

### Handlers e Threads

Para a diferença entre `Handler` e `Thread`, veja [esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/12105/diferen%C3%A7a-entre-handler-e-thread). Note que `Handlers` não são `Threads`; `Handlers` têm esse nome porque servem para entregar mensagens (uma mensagem ou `Message` é basicamente o encapsulamento de um `Runnable`, isto é, um trecho de código executável) para *threads* que ficam em *loop* aguardando a chegada desses trechos de código para executar.

Para um thread ficar em *loop*, é preciso criar uma fila de mensagens para ele chamando os métodos `Looper.prepare()` e `Looper.loop()` dentro do próprio *thread*. No caso do *thread* principal o próprio sistema já faz esses passos, de forma que já o encontramos em *loop* por padrão.

Usamos um `Handler` quando queremos que um *thread* secundário execute muitas mensagens, ou quando queremos entregar uma mensagem ao *thread* principal. Neste último caso podemos evitar o uso do `Handler` através do método `Activity.runOnUiThread()` (caso estejamos em uma `Activity`), ou através de uma `AsyncTask`.

### AsyncTasks

Uma `AsyncTask` é uma classe que permite executar três trechos de código em sequência: o primeiro será executado pelo *thread* principal (*thread* de UI), o segundo por um *thread* secundário, e o terceiro de novo pelo *thread* principal. Por debaixo dos planos isso é implementado usando `Threads` e `Handlers`.

`AsyncTasks` têm a intenção de simplificar a implementação dessa sequência de passos, que é muito comum de acontecer no Android (por exemplo: disparar uma animação de "carregando", executar uma tarefa em segundo plano, e então interromper a animação).

Essa sequência é feita assim, separada em *threads* e não tudo no mesmo *thread*, porque o *thread* principal é reservado para atualizar a tela e não pode executar tarefas em segundo plano sob pena de perder a responsividade.

Answer (score 3):

`AssyncTask` e `Handler` são classes utilizadas para facilitar o seu trabalho como desenvolvedor.

> AsyncTask enables proper and easy use of the UI thread. This class
>   allows to perform background operations and publish results on the UI
>   thread without having to manipulate threads and/or handlers

Traduzindo:

> AssyncTask permite a utilização adequada e facil de UI threads. Essa
>   classe permite executar operações em background e publicar resultados
>   na UI Thread sem precisar manipular Threads e/ou Handlers

E quanto aos Handlers:

> Handler allows you to send and process Message and Runnable objects
>   associated with a thread's MessageQueue

Traduzindo:

> Handlers permitem você enviar e processar Objetos de Mensagem e
>   Executáveis associados a uma Fila de Mensagens de uma Thread.

Cada `Thread` tem uma `Fila de Mensagens` em que ela busca para processá-las até que a fila esteja vazia. Essa fila de mensagens pode ser processada após o uso de Looper.prepare() e Looper.loop(), conforme lembrado pelo @Piovezan nos comentários e por [essa resposta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7597897/3293600). O `Handler` envia mensagens para essa fila para que elas sejam processadas.

Estes foram os pontos importantes [dessa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9800870/3293600) no SOen. Você pode olhar com mais detalhes nela.

Comment: Vale lembrar que um Thread por padrão não fica em _loop_ nem tem uma fila de mensagens. Para ele ter esse comportamento é preciso chamar `Looper.prepare()` e `Looper.loop()` dentro do próprio thread. O thread principal já vem com esse comportamento.

Comment: bem lembrado, inclui na resposta

Answer (score 1):

Se olharmos para o código fonte do `AsyncTask` e do `Handler` podemos perceber que o código é escrito puramente em Java. (Claro, existem algumas exceções , mas isso não é o mais importante).

Portanto, não há nenhum segredo entre `AsyncTask` e `Handler`. Eles apenas facilitam o nosso trabalho como desenvolvedor.

Por exemplo: se o **Programa A** chama o método A () , método A () poderia ser executado em um segmento diferente com o **Programa R**. Você pode facilmente verificar isso usando:

```
Thread t = Thread.currentThread();    
int id = t.getId();
```

Por que devemos usar um novo `Thread`? Muitas, muitas razões.

`Handler` e `AsyncTask`  são escritos em Java (internamente eles usam um `Thread`), então tudo o que você pode fazer com `Handler` ou `AsyncTask`, você pode conseguir usando um `Thread` também.

Quais são as vantagens de se utilizar o `Handler` ou o `AsyncTask`?

A razão mais óbvia é a **comunicação** entre o *caller thread* e o *worker thread*.

- *Caller Thread*: A thread que chama o *Worker Thread* para executar alguma tarefa. A Caller Thread não precisa ser a thread principal). É claro, você pode também comunicar entre duas threads através de outras maneiras, mas existem muitas desvantagens (e possíveis falhas) devido à problemas de segurança de thread.

A diferença entre `Handler` e`AsyncTask` é: Use `AsyncTask` quando *Caller thread* é a *UI Thread*.
A [documentação do Android](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) diz que:

> `AsyncTask` habilita a maneira coerente e fácil de usar a UI Thread. Esta classe
>   permite executar operações em background e depois publicar os resultados na UI thread sem se preocupar com manipulação de threads ou handlers envolvidos no processo.

Comment: A utilidade de `AsyncTask` está bem explicada, falta só explicar o que é um `Handler` em termos que um leitor casual entenda e também esclarecer para que ele serve (por exemplo, embora `Handlers` possam postar mensagens em _worker threads_, não faz sentido usar um `Handler` para um _thread_ que não esteja em _loop_ aguardando essas mensagens, como no caso de um _thread_ que irá executar somente uma tarefa).

Answer (score 0):

Cara, é simples. Os 2 (Thread e AsyncTask) tem o mesmo objetivo final, que é processar alguma ação em backgroud, dar uma resposta de progresso se necessário, e uma resposta (Handler) final. O AsyncTask é a forma mais legal de fazer tudo isso, ele surgiu depois e é sugerido para uso, além de ser bem mais fácil de utilizar.

Pra complementar, handler é uma forma de exibir uma resposta ao usuário através de uma Thread. O AsyncTask já tem isso implementado na classe, facilitando a utilização.

Espero ter ajudado!