# Processamento de Audio em tempo real no android: Thread ou AsyncTask?

Tags: java, android, thread, asynctask

Estou começando a desenvolver um app para android que irá "ouvir" o audio e irá desenhar a forma de onda dele na tela.
Mas o primeiro passo eu queria apenas "ouvir" o audio e mostrar na tela o valor lido em tempo real. E para fazer isso estou usando a classe Audio Record:

```
AudioRecord audioRecord= new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, TaxaAmostragem, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, minBufferSize);
```

Só que meio a dúvida de qual seria a melhor opção para fazer esse procesamento em tempo real: Thread ou AsyncTask? 
Pesquisando um pouco vi que a AsyncTask só é recomendada para aplicações que durem poucos segundos mas consultando materiais na net sobre isso vi alguns trabalhos que usam a Asynctask para fazer isso. Ai estou na duvida se posso ou não usar Asynctastk, já que ela é mais fácil de usar.

**EDIT** Ja tinha lido esse link e nele é dito o seguinte

> Esta restrição só se aplica se a AsyncTask for executada através do método execute(). Esse método executa as Tasks de forma sequencial, numa única thread, fazendo com que a Task seguinte só inicialize após a finalização da anterior.
>   A restrição pode ser evitada usando o método executeOnExecutor(), passado a ele um executor, normalmente AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, de forma a ser usada uma pool de threads para executar as tarefas em paralelo.

1. Então, se eu quiser usar a AsyncTask para realizar tarefas continuas, que vão ser executadas enquanto o app estiver aberto, eu posso fazer isso usando o método  executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR) em vez do execute() sem problemas ?
2. Meu app vai ter de fazer uso de outras threads para fazer outras tarefas, como baixar imagens por exemplo. Eu vou usar AsyncTask mas ao mesmo tempo a Asynctask do processamento do audio vai estar executando porque enquanto o app estiver aberto ela vai estar em execução. No caso eu poderia usar mais de uma Asynctask se eu usar o método executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR) ?
3. Nesse caso especifico qual seria a melhor opção: Usar Asynctask em paralelo ou usar Threads?

Comment: Relacionada: [Thread ou Asynctask? Quando e qual devo usar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/68056/thread-ou-asynctask-quando-e-qual-devo-usar)

Comment: nesse link : https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/82399/quais-são-as-principais-diferenças-entre-handler-thread-e-asynctask

Comment: @ArmandoMarquesSobrinho
A pegunta foi editada.
Obrigado desde já pela ajuda!

Comment: @Henriquea pergunta foi editada.

Comment: Ok @LucasJunior, entail, no caso especifico do som eu no seu caso usaria a thread, mesmo porque, pelo que pude compreender essa vai ser uma thread exclusiva, ou seja, soh para rodar o som, e também, porque uma asynctask eh uma thread, mas o controle dessa thread fica a critério dela mesma, enquanto que numa thread normal, o controle eh seu, isso tem uma grande diferença para quem programa, dai cria outro post especificando o problema que voce que resolver usando threads e a gente tenta ver juntos uma solução, eu jah tenho algo parecido aqui